# is it possible to change @Value field via listener?

Tags: spring-boot

I am wondering something but i don't know if it's possible :

in a RestController, i have:

```
@Value("${login}")
String login;
```

This value is set at runtime via a spring framework which populates this value from outside rest api call.

Let's say the value of 'login' changes on this outside referential.
My goal is to be able to implement a ConfigurationListener which interrogates periodically this remote referential and updates the login value of the runtime.

Is it something being achievable ?

Regards,
Guillaume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Spring Cloud Config](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config) to have dynamic configuration properties.

There is an article on this subject: [Centralized Configuration](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)

Look for `/refresh` endpoint and `@RefreshScope` annotation.

Comment: Thank you, i ended on this too, after finding some blogs
Hope your answer will help more people too !